# When using the word "too" as a negative quantifier of a plural noun, is it incorrect to use the construction: too + adj +of +plural noun?

Tags: grammar

Examples: 
There were too windy of conditions to go boating. 
Those parents have too strict of rules.

I usually reword the sentence to avoid this situation:

The conditions were too windy
The rules of those parents are too strict.

However, I would really like to know if the construction with "of"  is accepted as grammatically correct.

Comment: I have only come across that kind of usage with superlatives - "These are the windiest of conditions" (Weird) or "those parents impose the strictest of rules on their children". Is this usage with the too+positive something you would use or have seen others use casually, or are you just wondering-theorizing? What is your variety of English and is it native to you?

Comment: I am a native English speaker (American English) but I live in Sweden now. The construction with "too + adj + noun" is common in Swedish and so I hear it translated often when Swedes speak or write in English. I pose the question here because I have heard this construction so often that I am starting to wonder whether or not I am correct in saying that using it in the way I described is incorrect. I would like to be able to explain why using that specific construction in English is wrong.

Comment: I believe I have heard this, but I'd say it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only time you can use this is when the entire construction "<adjective> of <noun>" forms an adjectival phrase. The only example I can think of is when the adjective of the adjectival form of a verb and the noun is the object of the verb. Picking up the example of @BaridBaranAcharya, it is correct to say:

```
He is desirous of success
```

However in your example it is NOT correct to say

```
It is windy of conditions
```

The basic construction you are looking for is

```
It was too <adjective> to <verb>
```

We can drop "desirous of success" in place of <adjective> but not "windy of conditions. This means:

- "It is too windy of conditions to go boating" is **incorrect**
- "He is too desirous of success to come" is **correct**.

The following are correct:

- It is too windy to go boating
- Conditions are too windy to go boating
- Those parents have too strict rules

"It was too windy conditions to go boating" is technically wrong, but probably often enough used to be acceptable outside a grammar class.

Excepting the <adjectival-verb> of <object> construction, i**t is almost always wrong to use "<adjective> of <noun>"**, although it's a common mistake for English learners. You say "windy conditions" not "windy of conditions", "strict rules" not 'strict of rules".

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can come to justifying that construction is "Was it too mean of me to call him a grouchy old man?"

Answer (score 0):

"TOO+ADJECTIVE+OF+PLURAL NOUN"--Such construction is rare in normal usage.

OF= a simple preposition mainly used to mean possession and/or relation.

TOO= An adjunct adverbial modifier that comes before adjective and other adverb with a strong negative sense.
•He is too old to work.

The above sentence is a common usage of 'too' followed by an infinitive.

Yet another common construction of 'too' is where it is followed by a prepositional phrase.(preposition + its object+infitive)

•The milk is too hot for the baby to drink.

So such adjectives as are followed by " OF" may fit in the structure as in the poster.

•HE IS TOO DESIRIOUS OF SUCCESS TO COME.

So the the first example would be fine without "OF" and in the second one change the verb to "are" and retain "OF" as it is.

So we are conservative about use of "OF" if the demand of the preceding adjective doesn't so warrant.